# Trying to follow a link in an iframe using CasperJS

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, casperjs

I'm trying to use [CasperJS](http://casperjs.org/index.html) to follow a link that's in an iframe but I can't seem to get at the iframe's document.

Here's a test using an iframe example page I found.
The third iframe has a name attribute which I need for Casper's frame method. [Casper API](http://casperjs.org/api.html)

```
var casper = require('casper').create();

casper.start('http://nunzioweb.com/iframes-example.htm');

casper.withFrame('frame', function(){
  this.echo('Page url is ' + this.getCurrentUrl());
  this.echo(this.getHTML());
});

casper.run();
```

The page url comes back with "http://nunzioweb.com/lyrics/455Rocket.html" as I expected but the returned html is the page wrapping the iframe.

Any idea how I can get into the iframe so I can click a link [on the page I'm actually doing this with]?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For some reason `.getHTML()` doesn't work here, you have to get the page HTML
directly from the `WebPage` instance.

```
var casper = require('casper').create();

casper.start('http://nunzioweb.com/iframes-example.htm');

casper.withFrame('frame', function(){
    this.echo('Page url is ' + this.getCurrentUrl());
    this.echo(this.page.content);
});

casper.run();
```

I'll be working on that issue.

To click on a link, eg. on the `Slick City` one in your iframe example:

```
var casper = require('casper').create();

casper.start('http://nunzioweb.com/iframes-example.htm');

casper.withFrame('frame', function() {
    this.echo('Page url is ' + this.getCurrentUrl());
    this.clickLabel('Slick City');
});

casper.waitForPopup('slickcitydown.htm').withPopup('slickcitydown.htm', function() {
    this.echo('New page url is ' + this.getCurrentUrl());
});

casper.run();
```

That gives:

```
$ casperjs test.js 
Page url is http://nunzioweb.com/lyrics/455Rocket.html
New page url is http://nunzioweb.com/slickcitydown.htm
```

Comment: this.page.content still returns the outer page html with an empty iframe but I think this.clickLabel is working. I'm not exactly sure because phantom.js reliably crashes at that point. I tried this.click but it's unable to find the element.

Comment: This is all in an effort to navigate AT&T's wireless business account page since they don't give a nice app like they do for normal accounts. I'm just trying to cobble together a better way to get usage data. Just in case you were wondering. This is why I can't really post up exactly what I'm trying to navigate.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like in last versions the issue was fixed.

I'm using the code example from the question with casperjs v.1.0.2 and I'm getting the html of the iframe http://nunzioweb.com/lyrics/455Rocket.html as it's expected.