# Return the entire remote DOM using CasperJS

Tags: dom, screen-scraping, casperjs

I'm using CasperJS to do some screen scraping and I am running into a strange problem. When I navigate to a URL using my web browser the DOM looks entirely different from what CasperJS encounters when it navigates to the same URL.

To this end, I'd like to dump the remote DOM via CasperJS in order to troubleshoot what is going on.

Has anyone done such a thing?

Tips appreciated!

Comment: It could be that the site you are truing to scrape doesn't see a User-Agent it likes, and serves something else than the page you requested.

Comment: Yes User Agent solves my problem. Cheers!

Comment: [Probably related](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13949048/330911). Try to change the default User-Agent used by Casper using [Casper.userAgent()](http://casperjs.org/api.html#casper.userAgent).

Comment: I used this:    pageSettings : {
     userAgent : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1309.0 Safari/537.17',
    }